# Google PHP Client library "All day" Event repeat

Tags: php, google-api

Here's is my code

```
    if($service instanceof Google_Service_Calendar and isset($_SESSION['service_token']) and $_SESSION['service_token'] != '' ) {
                        $event = new Google_Service_Calendar_Event();
                        $event->setSummary('AllDay Event Bug');
                        $start = new Google_Service_Calendar_EventDateTime();
                        $start->setDateTime(date('Y-m-d\TH:i:s',strtotime('2015-11-11 10:00:00')));
                        $start->setTimeZone('Australia/Melbourne');
                        $event->setStart($start);
                        $end = new Google_Service_Calendar_EventDateTime();
                        $end->setDateTime(date('Y-m-d\TH:i:s',strtotime('2015-11-16 11:00:00')));
                        $end->setTimeZone('Australia/Melbourne');
                        $event->setEnd($end);
                        if(recurring) {

                            $recurrenceUntil = date('Ymd\THis\Z',strtotime('2015-11-16 11:00:00'));

                            if(count($exDateArr) > 0) {
                                $exdate = "EXDATE:".implode(",", $exDateArr);
                            } else {
                                $exdate = '';
                            }


                            switch ($repeate) {
                                case "day":
                                    $frequence = "DAILY";
                                    break;
                                case "week":
                                    $frequence = "WEEKLY";
                                    break;
                                case "month":
                                    $frequence = "MONTHLY";
                                    break;
                                case "year":
                                    $frequence = "YEARLY";
                                    break;
                            }

                            $event->setRecurrence(
                                array(
                                    "RRULE:FREQ=".$frequence.";UNTIL=".$recurrenceUntil.";INTERVAL=".$repeate_interval,
                                    $exdate
                                )
                            );

                        }

                        $newEvent = $service->events->insert('primary', $event);

}
```

When i search for that event in Google Calendar, this is the result i get.

```
Wed Nov 11, 2015   10:00am – 11:00am  AllDay Event Bug

Thu Nov 12, 2015   All day            AllDay Event Bug
                   10:00am – 11:00am  AllDay Event Bug

Fri Nov 13, 2015   All day            AllDay Event Bug
                   All day            AllDay Event Bug
                   10:00am – 11:00am  AllDay Event Bug

Sat Nov 14, 2015   All day            AllDay Event Bug
                   All day            AllDay Event Bug
                   All day            AllDay Event Bug
                   10:00am – 11:00am  AllDay Event Bug

Sun Nov 15, 2015   All day            AllDay Event Bug
                   All day            AllDay Event Bug
                   All day            AllDay Event Bug
                   All day            AllDay Event Bug
                   10:00am – 11:00am  AllDay Event Bug

Mon Nov 16, 2015   All day            AllDay Event Bug
                   All day            AllDay Event Bug
                   All day            AllDay Event Bug
                   All day            AllDay Event Bug
                   All day            AllDay Event Bug
                   10:00am – 11:00am  AllDay Event Bug
```

Everything is good on the first day , next day onwards an extra "All day" event is added, and it increments every day.Can anyone please tell me why this is happening ? 
I'm using Google Service Account Credentials and the event i've added is not a recurring one and there are no exception dates.